# Scale an image only by width or height

Tags: html, css

I have an image:

```
<img src="#" width="42" >
```

If I set only the width, Firefox and IE will scale also the height, but Chrome doesn't it keep the initial image height. Can Chrome behavior be fixed ?

If I set just the `height` is not taken in consideration. Can an image be scaled by height ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `height` to `auto` should work.  For example:

```
<img src="#" width="42" height="auto">
```

> If height: auto; the element will automatically adjust its height to allow its content to be displayed correctly.

This will work for all modern browsers and works for both `%` and `px`, `em` sizes ect.

See [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp)

Or using inline styles:

```
<img src="#" style="width:42; height:auto;">
```

---

*Edit:* I'm not sure you did not mean give height a value and make width resize automatically.  In which case `width: auto` should do fine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of letting HTML do the work, let CSS do it.

Change :

```
<img src="#" width="42" >
```

To :

```
<img src="#" style="width: 42px; height: auto;">
```

That will allow CSS to resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
.img
{
   width:auto;

   height:auto;
}
```

**You can define width and height in css**

Comment: In the example given by the OP the width is set to `42`, not auto.

Comment: I just give a simple example for his/her. We can write that width:42px;